# html.php form renders boolean radio button value to `on`

Tags: php, html, radio-button

So I have an html.php page that has three buttons: "Clear Page," "Retrieve," and "Update Details."

When a user first opens the form it is blank and they can either enter a id="siteId" value or an id="siteName" value and press the "Retrieve" button to have the rest of a stored site's details requested from a mySQL DB and displayed in the form.

If the user wants to alter/update any of the details they can do so in the same form and then click the "Update Details" button to push the site's details back to the DB.

All is (somewhat) good so far. But when the "Update Details" button is clicked after a site's details are successfully displayed (after a site's details have been Retrieved from the DB), any boolean data represented by radio buttons is returned as `on`, observed using `print_r` on an array of the current values.

For each of the radio buttons php conditionals are used inline with the html to determine which radio button should be `checked` for each row/field after data retrieval from the DB. Could this be why the form is somehow setting a value of `on` for all of the radio buttons when the Update button is pressed instead of the previously determine boolean values?

If so what might a fix be since I need to check via conditionals which radio button for any given set needs to be `checked`?

Snippet of html.php page:

```
  } // close isset IF

?>

  <h1 id="heading">Cell Site Details</h1>


  <!--fieldset id="Site:"-->
    <!--legend>Site:</legend-->
    <div id="formContentDiv">
      <form id="formContent" action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
        <div id="clearPageDiv">
          <a href="index2.php">
              <input type="button" id="buttonClear" name="clearPage" class="button" value="Clear Page">
            </a>
        </div><!-- closes clearPageDiv -->
        <div id="retreiveDiv">
          <input type="submit" id="buttonRetreive" name="retreive" class="button" value="Retreive">
        </div><!-- closes retreiveDiv -->
        <div id="updateDiv">
          <input type="submit" id="buttonUpdate" name="update" class="button" value="Update Details">
        </div><!-- closes updateDiv -->

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label>
            <span>Site Id:</span>
            <input type="text" id="siteId" name="siteId" class="textInputShort" maxlength="" $value=""> 
            <script>
              siteId.value = <?php echo json_encode( ucfirst( $siteId ) ); ?>;
            </script>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label>
            <span>Site Name:</span>
            <input type="text" id="siteName" name="siteName" class="textInput" maxlength="" $value="test"> 
            <!--input type="submit" value="Retreive"-->
            <script>
              siteName.value = <?php echo json_encode( ucwords( $siteName ) ); ?>;
            </script>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label>
            <span># HSPA BBUs:</span>
            <input type="text" id="numHspaBbu" name="numHspaBbu" class="textInputShort" maxlength="" $value=""> 
            <script>
              numHspaBbu.value = <?php echo json_encode( $numHspaBbu ); ?>;
            </script>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label>
            <span># LTE BBUs:</span>
            <input type="text" id="numLteBbu" name="numLteBbu" class="textInputShort" maxlength="" $value=""> 
            <script>
              numLteBbu.value = <?php echo json_encode( $numLteBbu ); ?>;
            </script>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label><span>Ext. Alarm Terminations:</span></label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="extAlarmsTerminated"
                <?php
                  if ( $extAlarmsTerminated == "hspa" ) {
                    echo 'checked';
                  }
                ?>
              >
              <span>HSPA</span>
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="extAlarmsTerminated"
                <?php
                  if ( $extAlarmsTerminated == "lte" ) {
                    echo 'checked';
                  }
                ?>
              >
              <span>LTE</span>
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="extAlarmsTerminated"
                <?php
                  if ( $extAlarmsTerminated == "hspa-lte" ) {
                    echo 'checked';
                  }
                ?>
              >
              <span>HSPA-and-LTE</span>
            </label>
          </label>
        </div><!-- close formRowDiv -->
```

var $extAlarmsTerminated is one such radio button group in the following array of site details:

```
$inputVals = array( $siteId, $siteName, $numHspaBbu, $numLteBbu, $extAlarmsTerminated );
    print_r( $inputVals );
```

`print_r` output showing first, the boolean radio button value displayed after user presses Retrieval button:

```
Array ( [0] => P6969 [1] => Toledo Centre [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => hspa-lte
```

`print_r` output showing the radio button value of the same site details after user presses Update Detail button:

```
Array ( [0] => P6969 [1] => Toledo Centre [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => on )
```

---

**EDIT:**
I assigned each of the field input values retreived from the DB to a PHP $_SESSION var, and when the Update Details button is clicked the $_SESSION vars are referenced, which has solved the original problem with the radio buttons being assinged `on`.

But I still cannot save any changes to details a user may make. I have looked into JS/AJAX as a possible way to achieve this, but the very little JS I do know makes me more dangerous that useful. Here is what I have been able to piece together reading multiple similar issues:

```
<div class="formRowDiv">
      <label>
        <span>Site Name:</span>
        <input type="text" id="siteName" name="siteName" class="textInput" maxlength="" $value="test"> 
        <script>
          siteName.value = <?php echo json_encode( ucwords( $siteName ) ); ?>;
        </script>
      </label>
    </div>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( "#siteName" ).on( 'change', function() {
          var siteName = document.getElementById( 'siteName' ).value;
          $.ajax ({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: { siteName : siteName },
            success: function( result ) {
              alert( 'Site Name value changed to: ' + siteName );
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

The good news is that I get the JS alert echoing the changed value for $siteName when its field input value is altered. I created the ajax.php file referenced in the same dir and it contains:

```
<?php
  echo ( $_GET[ 'siteName' ] );
?>
```

I thought I could then get access to this changed $siteName value with something like:

```
$siteName = $_GET[ 'siteName' ];
```

But apparently not. Is there indeed a way to access this changed PHP var that I think must be now stored in ajax.php?

Comment: If you want it to be something other than "on", you need to set the "value" attribute on the checkboxes as well. The code can't guess what the value should be.

Comment: well I can't reset the values from the DB again or that would negate any of the user's changes to any values altered. Maybe I need then to use javascript to grab the current value of the elements?

Comment: You have multiple checkboxes with the same names and without values, how are you expecting this to work? Without values, how would you know what checkbox is checked and what checkbox isn't and what values they suppose to contain?

Comment: I can use `$_SESSIONS` to save to and retrieve the value of the input fields, but then I am still faced with the problem of extracting changed values the user alters.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a `value=` property to each of the input checkboxes, for instance you code will be :

```
<input type="radio" name="extAlarmsTerminated" value='HSPA'
    ...
<input type="radio" name="extAlarmsTerminated" value='lte'
    ...
<input type="radio" name="extAlarmsTerminated" value='HSPA-lte'
```

the result : `print_r($_POST)` output  :

`Array ( [submitted] => true [update] => Update Details [siteId] => P6969 [siteName] => Toledo Centre [numHspaBbu] => 1 [numLteBbu] => 1 [extAlarmsTerminated] => HSPA-lte )`

> I thought I could then get access to this changed $siteName value with something like:
>
> $siteName = $_GET[ 'siteName' ];
>   But apparently not. 
>   Is there indeed a way to access this changed PHP var that I think must be now stored in ajax.php?

First, you're using POST not GET method, so you should rather be looking for $_POST['siteName']

Second,if you're trying to make sure the right values are passed then change this at your form `<form id="formContent" action="#" method="post" ...`

by
 `<form id="formContent" action="test.php" method="post" ...`
where test.php contains :

`<?php
  echo ( $_POST['siteName'] );
?>`